# Android, abort notification comes from parse push

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I check the `JSON`  that is comming from parse push that I'm sending from parse push and if it match with my filter, I save it in database otherwise if it doesn't  match, I want that user don't see it's notification at all.
checking and saving are working good, but I can't dismiss (abort) it when it's not matched.
I tried `this.abortBroadcast();` at `onReceived` and also `onPushReceive` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should not abort it, just you have to use a correct JSON format, like this:

```
{
"data": {
    "message": "Hello! World.",
    "title": "my title"
},
"is_background": false
}
```

is_background determine whether to show notification or not.